# Ambiguous call to Overloaded Function (const variety)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

How do I fix this error?

> error C2668: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::end' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

My code looks like this:

```
typedef map<int const *, float> my_map_t;
my_map_t _test;
my_map_t::const_iterator not_found = my_map_t::end();
if (_test.find(&iKeyValue) == not_found) {
    _test[iKeyValue] = 4 + 5; // not the actual code, but here for simplicity
}
```

The compiler complains that there's an ambiguous call to my_map_t::end(). This makes sense, because the only difference is the return type.

Normally you can disambiguate the call by casting the parameters, but end() has no parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: It look like `_test` is a type, not an instance (you've `typedef`'ed it!). Also, what is `my_map_t`? Does it take templated parameters (in which case `my_map_t::const_iterator` doesn't make sense) or not (in which case your `typedef` is wrong)?

Comment: You're right. I typed up that snippet in a hurry. I corrected so that it makes sense now. I left the my_map_t::end() in there to show where my thinking was wrong.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer your questions when you don't post your actual code? Don't "type up snippets in a hurry". Don't type up snippets *at all*. Show us your *actual* code, or code which you have verified contains the same problem. Code that introduces new errors, typos and bugs just makes it harder for us to determine which of the errors we're supposed to focus on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it appears that `my_map_t::end()` is static (otherwise you'd have to call it on an instance, e.g. `_test.end()`).  **Edit**:  Jesse Beder is right in his comment to the question; the code doesn't make much sense, since `_test` is a type, not an object.

Static member functions cannot be const-qualified (the const-qualification of a member function applies to the `this` pointer; static member functions have no `this` pointer).

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, I knew I forgot something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this speaks, exactly, to your problem because I'm a little unclear on how to interpret the question but this might be of help...

```
// BindingProblem.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>

typedef std::map<int*, float> my_map_t;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int iKeyValue;

    my_map_t _test;

    my_map_t::const_iterator not_found = _test.end();

    if (_test.find(&iKeyValue) == not_found)
    {
        _test[&iKeyValue] = 4 + 5; // not the actual code, but here for simplicity
    }

    return 0;
}
```